# Android DrawerLayout not showing primary content

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a problem with DrawerLayout. I managed to make a drawer, and that is not a problem. But primary content doesn't displays.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Holy Operating Systems!"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    class="com.app.fragments.CustomFragment"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried every possible combination. Even when I remove the fragment primary content still doesn't displays.

Can someone spot a problem?

Comment: You have multiple match parents, tried removing or changing one?

Comment: @Rykuno, what exactly do you mean? According to developer.android: position your primary content view as the first child with a width and height of match_parent

Answer (score 1):

last weeks, i have met this problem, the reason is the width and height which you
set. the follwing is my code. i hope can give you some advices.

`

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/dlNav"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--mian content-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/im_MainImage"
            android:src="@mipmap/a"
            />

    </FrameLayout>


    <!--DrawLayout the content-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dlContent"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffcc"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

at the first,i do not set the layout_gravity, it does not work. but I find you 
have it. i guess your problem is not the drawlayout.

Answer (score 0):

What a silly silly silly thing, or at least it's me.

The problem was that I had in my styles.xml under AppTheme this:

`<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>`

And it didn't want to work like that without displaying any error. 
Just in case someone does the same thing.